# Reindex just one particular record with sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, sunspot

I have two models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  searchable do
    text :post_titles
  end

  def post_titles
    posts.map &:title
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

the problem is that when I update title of the Post sunspot doesn't update index for related user and it is not searchable by new data. If I do `User.index` it solves problem but takes too much time. Are there any better solutions to update parent record index on child record change(like reindex just parent record and not all users)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sunspot provides an instance `index()` method, for indexing one record.

What I did was

```
 class Post 

   belongs_to :user
   after_save :update_user_index

 private

   def update_user_index
     user.index
   end
end
```

If you are running this in console, and want to see results immediately, call `Sunspot.commit`

Comment: Why do I always find a solution a few minutes after I asked a question at StackOverflow :\

Comment: Jeff Atwood has already talked about [this phenomenon](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) . Cheers!

Comment: Why do you have to do a Sunspot.commit? I have this code running in my app but I do not see any changes until I run Sunspot.commit in the console. Why do you need this only when from the console?

Comment: I can't say for sure what is the default policy regarding Sunspot.commit but there are two methods you can check index and index! second one triggers Sunspot.commit also.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone finding this answer in the future, the reason you need to call Sunspot.commit if working in the console is that sunspot's default behaviour is to wait for the end of the current request to commit any changes. Since there is no request, commit needs to be done manually. See: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/tree/master/sunspot_rails#committing